# Filter only rows with 0 value in multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to filter rows only if they contain 0 in multiple columns - I want to delete the rows. eg only rows where value is 0 in all columns E,F,G,H

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Select your data and create a [table with headers](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-867f3add-0522-493c-94ab-b1b9933f46ca).

Then, apply [numeric filters](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e#bmfilter_numbers) where the value equals "0".

This should isolate all the rows where the filtered columns have a value of "0".

Answer (score 0):

In cell **I2** enter:

**=4-COUNTIF(E2:H2,0)**

and copy down.

Then delete all rows in which column **I** has a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Another option suggested for this case: 
Create extra column and sum up the values in E-H columns. The ones with 0 are yours.