# Filter out rows with 0 from many columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to filter out 0's from rows across many columns.
However some of these rows may zero out. other times it works fine.

This solution is not working for me: [Filter only rows with 0 value in multiple columns](https://superuser.com/questions/919665/filter-only-rows-with-0-value-in-multiple-columns)

The solution of creating a helper column and sum the row, then filter out 0's does not work as some rows just = 0. (see photo). I cannot sum just some columns either, i need to just get rid of 0's across all columns.

[image]

Any one have any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

*This helps you:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put Zero in cell C220, is the critria.
- Enter Helper values 1 & 2, are in RED in A221 & B221, you need to extend this, since you have many columns.
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell D22, finish with
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$222:$B$225,SMALL(IF((INDEX($A$222:$B$225,,A$221)=$C$220),MATCH(ROW($A$222:$B$225),ROW($A$222:$B$225)),""),ROWS(D221:$D$221)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```

*Adjust cell references as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column which does a sum in which negatives cannot cancel out positives. For example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$Z2,$B2:$Z2)
```

By multiplying the negative numbers by themselves, they turn positive. Only a row full of zeroes can end up zero.

(I'm sure there's probably a way to do this with an array function and ABS, but I like the simplicity of this)